# Why I got a (400 Bad Request) for correct python request?

Tags: python, https, python-requests, http-status-code-400

I request the login data and verification using python requests. The login response me 200 OK, but the verification was 400 bad request !!

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import json

post_data = {
    'response_type': 'code',
    'scope': 'openid+offline_access',
    'redirect_uri': 'https:%3A%2F%2Fapi.asiamiles.com%2Fprofile%2Fapi%2Fv2%2FcreateSessionAndRedirect',
    'login_url': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.asiamiles.com%2Fen%2Flogin.html',
    'target_url': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.asiamiles.com%2Fen%2Faccount%2Faccount-overview.html',
    'state': '',
    'username': '1707990235',
    'password': '*123qweQWE',
}

url = 'https://api.cathaypacific.com/mlc2/authorize'
opener = requests.sessions.session()
temp = opener.post(url=url,data=post_data)
print(temp.status_code,temp.reason)

jsondata = {"channel": "Voice", "language": "en", "voiceCallLanguage": "", "username": "ltxbjhnomx", "Number": "972592781582"}
josned = json.dumps(jsondata)
urrl = 'https://api.asiamiles.com/profile/api/v1/1707990235/mobile-verify/send-mobile-code'
smsheader = {
    'Host': 'api.asiamiles.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://www.asiamiles.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'Referer': 'https://www.asiamiles.com/en/mobile-verification.html?targetURL=https://www.asiamiles.com/en/account/account-overview.html',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ar-EG,ar;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

verify = opener.post(url=urrl, data=josned, headers=smsheader)
print(verify.status_code, verify.reason, verify.text)
```

That is the result ...

```
200 OK
400 Bad Request {"errors":[{"errorCode":"CLSAPI_PRVB_01_2614","errorMessage":"Missing Mandatory field Customer Username or Number"}]}
```

actually, the login response must be 302 Found, and the verification must be send.
where is the error? how could I fix it!!

Comment: ***"how could I fix it!"***: Have you read the error message: ***`"errorMessage":"Missing Mandatory field Customer Username or Number"`***

Comment: stovfl, where could I add it ?!

Comment: You have to add it into `jsondata = {"Number": ...`

Comment: I edited it. it's still same problem !

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation about the `api` at `.asiamiles.com`

Comment: no I really ```don't``` have

Comment: try print the text of the login response and see if what is says. 200 OK might be response OK but text says failed login. Or maybe try put the username in the http header but it is impossible to say without knowing

Comment: @ZodiAbujayyab: Ask for support here [asiamiles support help-centre](https://www.asiamiles.com/en/support/help-centre/faq.html)